# Scikit-learn script giving vastly different results than the tutorial, and gives an error when I change the dataframes

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm working through a tutorial that has this section:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> from sklearn.linear_model.logistic import LogisticRegression
>>> from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split, cross_val_score
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data/sms.csv')
>>> X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['message'], df['label'])
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train_raw)
>>> X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test_raw)
>>> classifier = LogisticRegression()
>>> classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
>>> precisions = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='precision')
>>> print 'Precision', np.mean(precisions), precisions
>>> recalls = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='recall')
>>> print 'Recalls', np.mean(recalls), recalls
```

Which I then copied with few modifications:

```
ddir = (sys.argv[1])
df = pd.read_csv(ddir + '/SMSSpamCollection', sep='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, names=["label", "message"])
X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['label'], df['message'])


vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train_raw)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(X_test_raw)
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)


precisions = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='precision')
recalls = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='recall')


print 'Precision', np.mean(precisions), precisions
print 'Recalls', np.mean(recalls), recalls
```

However, despite there being next to no differences in the code, the results in the book are far better than mine:

Book: `Precision 0.992137651822 [ 0.98717949  0.98666667  1.          0.98684211  1.        ]`
 `Recall 0.677114261885 [ 0.7         0.67272727  0.6         0.68807339  0.72477064]`

Mine: `Precision 0.108435683974 [  2.33542342e-06   1.22271611e-03   1.68918919e-02   1.97530864e-01   3.26530612e-01]` `Recalls 0.235220281632 [ 0.00152053  0.03370787  0.125       0.44444444  0.57142857]`

Going back over the script to see what went wrong, I thought that line 18:

```
X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['label'], df['message'])
```

was the culprit, and changed `(df['label'], df['message'])` to `(df['message'], df['label'])`. But that gave me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Chapter4[B-FLGTLG]C[Y-BCPM][G-PAR--[00].py", line 30, in <module>
    precisions = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='precision')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1433, in cross_val_score
    for train, test in cv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 800, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 658, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 566, in _dispatch
    job = ImmediateComputeBatch(batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 180, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 72, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1550, in _fit_and_score
    test_score = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1606, in _score
    score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py", line 90, in __call__
    **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 1203, in precision_score
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/classification.py", line 984, in precision_recall_fscore_support
    (pos_label, present_labels))
ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['ham', 'spam'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

What could be the problem here? The data is here: http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection in case anyone wants to try.

Comment: Is that the same data that the tutorial was using to get the results it shows?

Comment: Yes. From the book: `We will use the SMS Spam Classification Data Set from the UCI Machine Learning Repository. The dataset can be downloaded from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection. First, let's explore the data set and calculate some basic summary statistics using pandas`

Comment: Why did you include the `sep="\t"` argument (and the other arguments in your `read_csv` call)?  Did you check to see that the data was imported correctly?  If the tutorial was using the same data, and it didn't use `"\t"`, then presumably the data are comma-separated, not tab-separated.

Comment: Actually, that line was glitching, and so I replaced the one in the book with one from here: http://radimrehurek.com/data_science_python/. The lines in `SMSSpamCollection` are space-seperated, but the content is the same as sms.csv, which I don't have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error at the end of the stacktrace is the key to understand what's going on here.

> ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['ham', 'spam'], 
>         dtype='|S4')

You're trying to score your model with precision and recall.  Recall that these scoring methods are formulated in terms of true positives, false positives, and false negatives.  But how does `sklearn` know what is positive and what is negative?  Is it 'ham' or 'spam'?  We need a way to tell `sklearn` that we consider 'spam' the positive label and 'ham' the negative label.  According to the `sklearn` documentation, the precision and recall scorers by default expect a positive label of `1`, hence the `pos_label=1` part of the error message.

There are at least 3 ways to go about fixing this.

**1. Encode 'ham' and 'spam' values as 0 and 1 directly from the data source in order to accommodate the precision/recall scorers:**

```
# Map dataframe to encode values and put values into a numpy array
encoded_labels = df['label'].map(lambda x: 1 if x == 'spam' else 0).values # ham will be 0 and spam will be 1

# Continue as normal
X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['message'], encoded_labels)
```

**2. Use `sklearn`'s built-in function (`label_binarize`) to transform the categorical data into encoded integers in order to accommodate precision/recall scorers:**

This will transform your categorical data to integers.

```
# Encode labels
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
encoded_column_vector = label_binarize(df['label'], classes=['ham','spam']) # ham will be 0 and spam will be 1
encoded_labels = np.ravel(encoded_column_vector) # Reshape array

# Continue as normal
X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['message'], encoded_labels)
```

**3. Create scorer objects with custom arguments for `pos_label`:**

As the documentation says, the precision and recall scores by default have a `pos_label` argument of `1`, but this can be changed to inform the scorer which string represents the positive label.  You can construct scorer objects that have different arguments with `make_scorer`.

```
# Start out as you did originally with string labels
X_train_raw, X_test_raw, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['message'], df['label'])
# Fit classifier as normal ...


# Get precision and recall
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, make_scorer
# Precision
precision_scorer = make_scorer(precision_score, pos_label='spam')
precisions = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring=precision_scorer)
print 'Precision', np.mean(precisions), precisions

# Recall
recall_scorer = make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label='spam')
recalls = cross_val_score(classifier, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring=recall_scorer)
print 'Recalls', np.mean(recalls), recalls
```

After making any of these changes to your code, I'm getting average precision and recall scores of around `0.990` and `0.704`, consistent with the book's numbers.

Of all the 3 options, I recommend #3 the most because it is harder to get wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was really bugging me. Can I ask *how*, though? The data dosn't have any headers: http://pastebin.com/rm3gyaGE

Comment: The data gets headers when you import the csv as a pandas dataframe and specify the names for each column, as in names=["label", "message"].  The first column will have the header 'label', and the second column with have the header 'message'.

Comment: I'm not sure why it worked at all when you had the label and the message arguments switched in test_train_split.  This simply shouldn't work.  It basically is asking the model to predict that if I have an email I know is 'spam', what's the likelihood that the message was 'some really long message'. Doesn't make much sense, right?  Something really screwy was happening there. After you changed it, you were setting the arguments correctly.  However, the target label was in a format that the scorer couldn't make sense of.  The precision and recall scorers need to know what the positive label is.